# Stratified K-Fold For Multi-Class Object Detection?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, object-detection, cross-validation

### Updated

I've uploaded a dummy data set, link [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o7Go9ccHwxFbZLMAOJeyvTJBUwrJ9TO1/view?usp=sharing). The `df.head()`:

[image]

It has **4 class** in total and `df.object.value_counts()`:

```
human    23
car      13
cat       5
dog       3
```

---

I want to do properly `K-Fold` validation splits over a multi-class object detection data set.

### Initial Approach

To achieve proper k-fold validation splits, I took the `object counts` and the number of `bounding box` into account. I understand, the `K-fold` splitting strategies mostly depends on the data set (meta information). But for now with these dataset, I've tried something like as follows:

```py
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=101)
df_folds = main_df[['image_id']].copy()

df_folds.loc[:, 'bbox_count'] = 1
df_folds = df_folds.groupby('image_id').count()
df_folds.loc[:, 'object_count'] = main_df.groupby('image_id')['object'].nunique()

df_folds.loc[:, 'stratify_group'] = np.char.add(
    df_folds['object_count'].values.astype(str),
    df_folds['bbox_count'].apply(lambda x: f'_{x // 15}').values.astype(str)
)

df_folds.loc[:, 'fold'] = 0
for fold_number, (train_index, val_index) in enumerate(skf.split(X=df_folds.index, y=df_folds['stratify_group'])):
    df_folds.loc[df_folds.iloc[val_index].index, 'fold'] = fold_number
```

After the splitting, I've checked to ensure if it's working. And it seems Ok so far.

[image]

All the folds contain stratified `k-fold` samples, `len(df_folds[df_folds['fold'] == fold_number].index)` and no intersection to each other, `set(A).intersection(B)` where `A` and `B` are the index value (`image_id`) of two folds. But the issue seems like:

```
Fold 0 has total: 18 + 2 + 3 = 23 bbox
Fold 1 has total: 2 + 11 = 13 bbox
Fold 2 has total: 5 + 3 = 8 bbox
```

### Concern

However, I couldn't ensure whether it's the proper way for this type of task in general. I want some advice. Is the above approach OK? or any issue? or there is some better approach! Any sorts of suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Innat, i am facing the same situation a would like to know if there are any improvements you did to the above approach ?

Answer (score 3):

When creating a cross-validation split, we care about creating folds which have a good distribution of the various "cases" encountered in the data.

In your case, you decided to base your folds on the number of cars and the number of bounding boxes which is a good but limited choice. So, if you can identify specific cases using your data/metadata, you might try to create smarter folds using it.

The most obvious choice is to balance object types (classes) in your folds, but you could go further.

Here is the main idea, let's say you have images with cars encountered mostly in France, and others with cars encountered mostly in the US, it could be used to create good folds with a balanced number of french and us cars in each fold. Same could be done with weather conditions etc. Thus, each fold will contain representative data to learn from so that your network won't be biased for your task. As a result, your model will be more robust to such potential real life changes in the data.

So, can you add some metadata to your cross-validation strategy to create a better CV? If it's not the case, can you get information about potential corner cases using the x, y, w, h columns of your dataset?

Then you should try to have balanced folds in terms of samples so that your scores are evaluated on the same sample size which will reduce variance and provide a better evaluation at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Among all the given answers, this one is close enough within the bounty award timeline. But I would mark as a right answer if it has some minimum code demonstration too.

Answer (score -1):

You can use StratifiedKFold() or StratifiedShuffleSplit() directly to split your data set using stratified sampling based on some categorical column.

Dummy Data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(43)
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': (1,1,2,2,3,3),
               'Object': ('bus', 'car', 'bus', 'bus', 'bus', 'car'),
               'X' : np.random.randint(0, 10, 6),
               'Y' : np.random.randn(6)

})


df
```

**Using StratifiedKFold()**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2)

for train_index, test_index in skf.split(df, df["Object"]):
        strat_train_set_1 = df.loc[test_index]
        strat_test_set_1 = df.loc[test_index]

print('train_set :', strat_train_set_1, '\n' , 'test_set :', strat_test_set_1)
```

**Similarly, if you choose to use StratifiedShuffleSplit(), you can have**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit

sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
# n_splits = Number of re-shuffling & splitting iterations.

for train_index, test_index in sss.split(df, df["Object"]):
 # split(X, y[, groups]) Generates indices to split data into training and test set.

        strat_train_set = df.loc[train_index]
        strat_test_set = df.loc[test_index]

print('train_set :', strat_train_set, '\n' , 'test_set :', strat_test_set)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, I think you misunderstood my query. I don't care about using `StratifiedKFold()` or `StratifiedShuffleSplit()`.  My concern is to make a proper validation strategy for multi-class object detection. And for that, My approach was to take account of the `object` type and number of the `bbox`. However, if you see in my query I'm already using `StratifiedKFold()`.

Answer (score -2):

I'd do this simply using `KFold` method of scikit-learn of python

```
from numpy import array
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
data = array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6])
kfold = KFold(3, True, 1)
for train, test in kfold.split(data):
    print('train: %s, test: %s' % (data[train], data[test]))
```

and please see if [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171413/k-fold-cross-validation-for-multi-class) might be helpful