# Tensorflow 2 Object Detection API - Can/Should I use K-Fold Cross Validation?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, cross-validation, object-detection-api

I have a small dataset of about **1000** images and am training my model to detect 8 classes. I had divided my dataset in a ratio of `80:20` (training: validation) and wanted to apply k-fold cross validation so as to make the most of my dataset.

#1: Is this line of thinking proper or am I misunderstanding something? In another post about **K-fold** cross-validation in object detection, someone mentioned that since we have confidence scores, we don't require k fold cross-validation. However, I don't see a correlation between training my model on the 'k' number of folds and confidence scores.

#2: Is this something that has to be manually done or does tensorflow 2.x have the means to add k fold cross-validation?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your query **1** and **2**

- (**IMO**), It would be proper to do **K-Fold**. FYI, splitting the data set into the `8:2` ratio is something called the **holdout** method, AFAIK, it's not **K-Fold**. When you want to do **K-Fold** there is something you probably need to consider such as **class distribution**, **bounding box distribution**, etc. However, as you don't provide any sample data or code, here is a similar [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64164932/stratified-k-fold-for-multi-class-object-detection) that might help you.
- It has to be manually done. It's a resampling procedure used to evaluate machine learning models on a limited data sample. It's not something integrated with any framework.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Indeed, the 8:2 ratio is not k fold. I was simply pointing out what i was currently doing. With regards to performing the kfold validation manually, how would i go about doing that (for object detection in tf2)? Would i have to generate multiple tfrecords and train on them after every 'n' steps/iterations? For eg. if i have 3 folds, would i have to train my model 3 times over (taking into consideration the latest checkpoint)?

Comment: Check [this](https://www.kaggle.com/davidtong/efficientdet-tpu-train-1-epoch-in-4-min/notebook) work.

Comment: You can also see how to generate tfrecord files, [here](https://www.kaggle.com/davidtong/wheat-gen-tf/notebook).